# Modify specific information in Firebase Database Realtime collection with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, real-time

I have a problem and I want to modify some information not all, for example I want to modify only the address and the nit (see image) but in doing so I delete the other fields, how could I modify it without eliminating the rest?

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bu9Mm.png)
My code:

```
        var uid = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
        var modi = {
            nombre: "Hello",
            direccion: "Address"
        }
        var updates = {};
        updates['/Users/' + uid] = modi;

        firebase.database().ref().update(updates);
```

Thank, you!

Answer (score 0):

Do you have access to that `User` object data?

If so, basically merge the updates into that and then save to Firebase. E.g.

```
// if we already have some reference to User data object
var updates = {...userObject, ...modi};
firebase.database().ref('/Users/' + uid).update(updates);
```

else you can always fetch that object, then do the merge and update procedure above. E.g.

```
// modi defined above
return firebase.database().ref('/Users/' + uid)
  .once('value')
  .then(function(snapshot) {
    var user = snapshot.val()
    updates = {...user, ...modi}
    firebase.database().ref('/Users/' + uid).update(updates);
  });
```